# simple DB design question

Tags: mysql, database, orm

This is probably a very stupid question, but I am just not sure which solution is the most elegant and the best(most performant) way to go in the following scenario.

I have the following tables:

Customer, Company, Meter, Reading

all of the tables above the line are supposed to be linked to one or more records of a "Comment" table. Which is the best way to model this relationship?

I am seeing two solutions here:

1.) use m:n relationships: CustomerComment, CompanyComment, etc. -> easy to extend later on, but a lot of new tables
2.) use 1:n relationships: Comment table has a field for the PK of the tables above (Customer_id, Company_id, ...) -> minimal table approach, but "harder" to extend since I would have to add a new field to the comment table whenever there is a new table that needs to be have comments

The target is a modular application, which may or may not have any of those four tables.

Which one is the better one - or are there more?

Thanks!

Comment: Can a comment that refers to a Customer at the same refer to a Company, too?

Comment: No, it cannot. Basically the idea is to have one single table for all comments and just have all the other entities use that table to drop their comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem with using integers for primary keys. You have a few solutions you can use.

The true unique ID for any given row for Customer, Company, Meter, Reading is a UUID. Maybe because of the database design the primary key has to be an integer but that is ok. This means you never have to add fields to the COMMENTS table if you have a new type in your system. It will always reference by the types ID.

Your tables can look like this:

```
CUSTOMER
   ID UUID

COMPANY
   ID UUID

METER
   ID UUID

COMMENTS
   ID
   RELATED_TO UUID
   COMMENT TEXT
```

Now you can attach comments to any table that has a unique ID.

If you want to support referential constraints

OBJECT is a table that holds all of the ID's of all the pieces of data you have in your system. We really start building a system in which you can associate any comment with anything you want. This may not be suitable in your design.

```
OBJECT
   ID UUID 

CUSTOMER
   ID UUID
   FOREIGN_KEY (ID) REFERENCES OBJECT(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE

COMPANY
   ID UUID
   FOREIGN_KEY (ID) REFERENCES OBJECT(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE

METER
   ID UUID
   FOREIGN_KEY (ID) REFERENCES OBJECT(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE

COMMENTS
   ID
   RELATED_TO UUID
   COMMENT TEXT
   FOREIGN_KEY (RELATED_TO) REFERENCES OBJECT(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This complicates the design in order to assure you don't need to add 2 tables for each new type in the system. Each design has sacrifices. In this one you've complicated things by saying for every each entry whether it be Company, Customer, Meter I need an associated ID int he Object table so I can put a foreign key on it.

Comment: Interesting. With your approach can you still use foreign key constraints or do you have to take of referential integrity yourself?

Comment: @Hyperboreus You can do referential constraints if you really want to I'll update my example. It will be very foreign to a lot of database designers though.

Comment: I had in mind maybe create a table tblUUID that holds all given UUIDS and then reference from Customer, Company, etc and from Comments to this table. Or is there some smarter way to do this?

Comment: @Hyperboreus That seems to be what I updated the Answer with. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this was my plan, too. Wicked. Can you this way create a new customer with a autogenerated UUID in one statement, or do you need to create the object first and then the new customer with the generated UUID?

Comment: Great idea. Reminds me a bit of the SharePoint 2010 datamodel approach for document-ids. Unfortunatly all tables have to use integers, so the UUID approach cannot be implemented.

Comment: Why can't the UUID not be an integer? As long as you don't have more entities than 2**64 (or 2**32 or whatever MAXINT is in your DBMS) there will be no problem using integer as the storage class for the UUIDS.

Comment: True. Though I would have to make sure that the Ids do not overlap. I think this concept is very intriguing, though unfortunatly not useful for my current problem. I will go with the m:n approach. (Same problem: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/90/aentityct9.png/)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer one for each pair - CustomerComment, CompanyComment, etc. It eventually will speed up your queries, and while it isn't as 'extensible' as a single CommentLink table, you'll need to make schema changes when you add something else that needs comments anyway.

Comment: So do you mean to have one Comment table for each (e.g. CustomerComment (id, comment_text, comment_type, etc)) or to have a mappingtable (e.g. CustomerComment(customer_id(PK),comment_id(PK))?

Answer (score 0):

I would use seperate tables, that way you can keep the referential constraints simple.